# Want to work login with strtolower

Tags: php, authentication

how can I create system for example when to my mySQL was inserted nickname: ,,Sprunkas'' and say can login not only with ,,Sprunkas'' but with ,,SPRUNKAS'', ,,sprunkas'' and etc. ? Here is some my PHP code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['jungtis'])) {

        if($_POST['login_slapyvardis'] != "" && $_POST['login_slaptazodis'] != "") {

            $login_slapyvardis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_slapyvardis']);
            $login_slaptazodis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_slaptazodis']);
            $apsaugotaslogin_slaptazodis = md5($login_slaptazodis);

            if($login_db == $login_sumazintas) {

            $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ucp_users WHERE name='$login_slapyvardis'") or die(mysql_error());
            $mysqlskc = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ucp_users WHERE name='$login_slapyvardis'"));
            $login_sumazintas = strtolower($login_slapyvardis);

            $login_db = strtolower($mysqlskc['name']);

                    $mysqli = mysql_fetch_array($mysql);

                    if($mysqli['password'] == $apsaugotaslogin_slaptazodis) {

                        $_SESSION['Logged'] = $mysqli['id'];
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        mysql_query("UPDATE ucp_users SET lastip = '$ip' WHERE id = '$mysqli[id]'");
                        header('Location: /home');
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to convert the post username into lowercase before querying the database.

```
$login_slapyvardis = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['login_slapyvardis']));
```

Then in your sql you need to use the LOWER function.

```
name=LOWER($login_slapyvardis)
```

Comment: Or just `LOWER(name) = LOWER($login_slapyvardis)`

Comment: Now it says that this nickname doesn't exists.

Comment: Thanks. Solved, but now it says, that password is incorrect... :D